# reading from multiple databases in one class

Tags: nhibernate

im a newbee to nhibernate and would like to do the following.

i have two classes classA, classB, with a many-to-one relation but the table with data for classA not in the same database as the table with the data for classB.

```
classA
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public int classB_Id {get; set;}
}

classB
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
 public  string SomethingElse {get; set;}
}
```

my mapping

```
<class name="ClassA" table="ClassATable">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" />
    <many-to-one name="ClassB" column="ClassBId" />
  </class>
```

Is it possible using NHibernate to create a mapping so that this can be readed with selecting first from databaseA, after that from databaseB ? i cannot find a solution how to set the configuration, so that it works.

If you have some helpfull links, please let me know !

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate does not support cross-db object graphs. 
You cannot  create an association between classs A and B when A and B live on different dbs. 
The only way to do this, is to define a property on classA which uniquely identifies an object of classB, and to use that property to load classB